# Tracking a disappearing thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a thread that suddenly just dies on me.

The thread main loop is like:

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            <snip>
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and I start it like:

```
    thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, throwable) -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    });
```

I have a very repeatable situation in which the program stops working and when I invoke Eclipse debugger this thread is nowhere to be seen.

How can this happen and how can I trace it, I would have thought my code would catch all possible ways the thread could exit and I would get a stack trace of what is going on….

Comment: Stupid question, did you call `start`?

Comment: If your while loop contains a `break;` then the code will happily exit your loop and the thread will end (assuming you started it in the first place).

Comment: Good point! I will need to add at least a print statement there! Should have seen that.

Comment: Forgot to answer: yes I call start(), the thread runs just fine until the user does executes a specific 'command' that results in an attempt to clear a specific queue between this disappearing thread and an other thread. If I remove that queue clear then this particular thread won't disappear.

Comment: about the 'break' possibility, I tried to add a println() statement after the loop but Eclipse refuses with "unreachable code" so I guess there can be no break there that is causing this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping as much code, at the highest level, with a try/finally block. This should always catch when the code exits the block unless System.exit() is called.

As you discovered, one way the code might drop out silently is if you used `return;` without realising it.

---

You Uncaught Exception Handler will only handle *uncaught* exceptions.  In this case you appear to be catching all exceptions.

The method called when you do have an uncaught exception is in Thread.

```
/**
 * Dispatch an uncaught exception to the handler. This method is
 * intended to be called only by the JVM.
 */
private void dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
    getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I would have expected that the try/catch throwable in the run loop of the tread would catch everything, the uncaught handle was just to see if something is not caught. But neither on is ever executed although the thread dies...

Comment: If you are in a state where the stack trace cannot be printed eg you are out of memory, you can find there is no error printed.

Comment: I don't think I'm out of memory as the program keeps running otherwise fine. To debug this further I inserted a print statement to an other thread that continuously prints the mystery threads isAlive() status and indeed, it suddenly changes from true to false, so while the object is there the thread dies silently and thus the debugger will not show it. But the mystery remains, what is the cause of the premature death and why I cannot see it.

Comment: @nyholku This sounds like a low level bug if you cannot trace it.  Can you put a try/finally at the highest possible level in the run() and see if the finally block is called?  Which version of Java do you have?

Comment: found the problem, pretty silly, in one code path inside the loop in a switch statement I had used return instead of break. Doh!

But, had I used finally as you suggested (found the bug before I saw your suggestion) I would have seen that actually this was just a 'normal' exit from the loop and I would have found the bug that way for sure.

So if you want to put up an answer about using 'finally' to trace the issue I will accept it and let you have the brownie points.